# Quick Python Regex Question: Matching negated sets of characters

Tags: python, regex

I want to find strings that do NOT match a particular sequence of characters. For example:

something like

```
REGEX = r'[^XY]*'
```

I'd like to look for strings that have any number of characters except an X and Y next to each other...the REGEX above doesn't work since it blocks X's and Y's separately.

Comment: I don't know much about python regex but what you have should work. Alternatively try replacing the `*` with `+`

Comment: I just checked that at http://nmichaels.org/regular.py and it seems to work fine. Can you give us a string to test it against?

Comment: I also don't know what you mean about blocking Xs and Ys separately. This regex will *ignore* Xs and Ys...

Comment: Can you not just match strings that *do* have XY together, then do whatever you want with the ones that don't?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Is `"XY" not in string` what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
if "XY" not in s:
   print "matched"
else
   print "not matched"
```

Or is this for inclusion in some longer regexp?  Then maybe you want a negative lookahead expression:

```
REGEXP="...(?!XY)..."
```

**EDIT:** fixed typo

Comment: I think you've got an extra `not` in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do that.

```
^(?!.*XY).*$
```

The lookahead expression tries to match a `XY` sequence anywhere in the string.  It's a *negative* lookahead, so if it finds one, the match attempt fails.  Otherwise the `.*` goes ahead and consumes the whole string.

```
^(?:(?!XY).)*$
```

This one repeatedly matches any character (`.`), but only after the lookahead confirms that the character is not the beginning of a `XY` sequence.

```
^(?:[^X]+|X(?!Y))*$
```

Repeatedly matches one or more of any character except `X`, or `X` if it's not followed by `Y`.

With the first two regexes, you have to apply the DOT_ALL modifier if their might be newlines in the source string.  The third one doesn't need that because it uses a negated character class - `[^X]` - instead of a dot.